# How to fix permalink - ?q=%2F appears in link not working wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

When I'm adding a page to my website ?q=%2F appears in the permalink and the page is redirecting to 'home'. I tried to change the permalink structure and did some changes to solve this in the .htaccess file but nothing worked so far. Is anybody known with this problem and how to solve this?